# Regular Expression is unsupported on Safari, but work in other browser like chrome, firefox, edge, etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, web, safari

I got an error when access my application on safari

It says:
The following regex is working just fine on Chrome, but it breaks in Safari with the following error: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name.

I am new at Regex, so I have no clue why it not working on Safari, but works well in other browser

Currently, i am using the regex to set amount of number like this:

`setAmount = (amount) => { const value = amount ? amount.replace(/(?<!\..*)(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))/g, '$1.') : 0; return value; }`

this code is used to display payment price

```
const nominal = formData.amount;


<Grid item xs={6}>
            <NumericFormat 
              className={classes.formControl}
              fullWidth
              thousandSeparator='.'
              color='primary'
              decimalSeparator=','
              prefix='Rp.'
              label='Amount'
              customInput={TextField}
              value={nominal}
              variant="outlined"
              disabled={true}
            />
          </Grid>
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you explain what the code is meant to do with input/output examples, and maybe we can offer a solution?

Comment: the code is meant to get a value of a payment price

const nominal = formData.amount;

<Grid item xs={6}>
                <NumericFormat 
                  className={classes.formControl}
                  fullWidth
                  thousandSeparator='.'
                  color='primary'
                  decimalSeparator=','
                  prefix='Rp.'
                  label='Amount'
                  customInput={TextField}
                  value={nominal}
                  variant="outlined"
                  disabled={true}
                />
              </Grid>

Comment: Hi. Did you understand what I meant by "input/output examples". Add those to your question. There maybe a better solution but without seeing a wide range of concrete examples it's difficult to tell. You might want to take a look at [https://regex101.com](https://regex101.com) which allows you to test patterns using a "flavor" of regex of your choice, and they're listed on the left.

Comment: It's probably because you have a quantifier inside of a negative lookbehind group. Javascript can technically do that, but not all browsers support it. Also, your regex pattern is rather strange and probably not doing what you think it's doing, due to the `(?:\d{3})+` within the positive lookahead. https://regex101.com/r/GjWmiE/1

Comment: *"It says: The following regex is working just fine on Chrome"*: I honestly doubt that Safari would say that.

Comment: @trincot I don't know what you mean by this comment. I don't have experience with Safari, but I'd be willing to bet if you remove the quantifier within the negative lookbehind, you won't get this error anymore. If you provide your input and expected output, I could probably give you a regex pattern that suites your needs.

Comment: @CAustin, I mean that it is unlikely that an error message originating from Safari is going to use the word "Chrome". My comment is not questioning that there is an error message, or how it can be solved (I already provided an answer at the time I made the comment), but about the citation of the error message itself. The author probably moved sentences around while editing and ended up putting them in the wrong sequence. But it would be good they corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Safari has no support yet for look behind assertions, although at the time of writing we know it is [coming to Safari too](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind). In this case you could actually omit the look behind assertion and instead **match** the substring in that condition and reproduce it in the output:

```
.replace(/\.(.*)|(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))/g, '$2.$1')
```

Here, if a point is encountered, all the rest of the input is captured and it gets reproduced by `.$1`. If the alternate (main) case occurs -- where a dot must be inserted -- then the digit is captured and is reproduced with the additional dot as `$2.`. Note that the two capture groups are mutually exclusive, so either `$1` or `$2` will be the empty string.

Here are some test runs:

```js
const setAmount = (amount) => {
    const value = amount ? amount.replace(/\.(.*)|(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))/g, '$2.$1') : 0;
    return value;
}

for (const test of ['1234567', '1.234.567', '1234.50', '-12', '-12345678.9']) {
    console.log(test, setAmount(test));
}
```

Taking a step back you might want to solve the formatting of numbers differently. The [`Number#toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) method can format numbers with thousands separators, and you can pass a locale so to influence the grouping and grouping character that is used.

For instance:

```js
const amount = "1234567.89";
const value = +amount; // Convert to number
for (const locale of ['en', 'fr', 'de']) { // Try some different locales
    console.log(locale, value.toLocaleString(locale));
}
```